# agment.onCreatePreferences at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:228)

Tags: java, android

I tried to create a settings activity for my android app but when I click the button that it's supposed to open the settings activity I get the following errors and my app goes back to my main activity.

Errors:

```
agment.onCreatePreferences(SettingsFragment.java:10)
        at androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:228)
```

Files mentioned by the errors:

PreferenceFragmentCompat.java

```
       ... // Fallback to default theme.
        theme = R.style.PreferenceThemeOverlay;
    }
    mStyledContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), theme);

    mPreferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(mStyledContext);
    mPreferenceManager.setOnNavigateToScreenListener(this);
    final Bundle args = getArguments();
    final String rootKey;
    if (args != null) {
        rootKey = getArguments().getString(ARG_PREFERENCE_ROOT);
    } else {
        rootKey = null;
    }
    onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState, rootKey); <---line 228
} ...
```

SettingsFragment

```
package com.example.padmw;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    }
}
```

And also my Settings activity

```
    package com.example.padmw;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Objects;


public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);



        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Settings");

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!= null)
        {
            if(savedInstanceState !=null)
                return;

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

I also get an "Cannot resolve symbol 'R'" in on in the PreferenceFragmentCompat.java  in "R.style.PreferenceThemeOverlay;"

So what is the problem and what should I do? 
If you need more info, please let me know.

I add that those errors appeared after I replaced getFragmentManager with getSupportFragmentManager 
in here :

```
    package com.example.padmw;


import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Objects;


public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);



        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Settings");

        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!= null)
        {
            if(savedInstanceState !=null)
                return;

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,new SettingsFragment()).commit();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors disappeared after I deleted the line "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);"